# Every firefox window defaults to 'show on all desktops' with windows 10 after trying the 'show this window on all desktops' feature once

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I tried Windows 10 'show this window on all desktops' once with Firefox -- now all new Firefox windows are pinned to all my desktops.

Cannot find anything on google due to the words 'pinning' and 'desktops' mostly bringing up results related to the sidebar and not to the multiple-desktops feature.

Here's a screen recording of it happening: https://streamable.com/mb114g

Answer (score 1):

I tried to duplicate what you describe with Firefox 78.0.2 on Windows 10 1903, and "Show on all desktops" worked as expected. The text in the video you posted is a bit too small to read easily, but it looks like "Show windows from this app on all desktops" is turned on. That would cause all Firefox windows to appear on all desktops.